# Not able to update the column value in the sqlite3

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I am new to the iPhone programming and was hoping that someone would be able to help me out with a problem that I've been trying to fix for a few days now.  I have created a database and a table. In my program, it contain 5 fields and I am setting two of the fields to zero. And later I am updating these fields to one for a purpose. But the problem is I am not able to set the field value to one. I will paste the code below :

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE TODOLIST_03 SET DELETEROW ='1' WHERE TASK=\"%@\"", cellText1];

const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(TODOLIST_03_DB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{   
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        .........   
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what is the error in the query?

Comment: First try to execute this query into `SQLite Manager` if its updating then probably there's mistake in code or query! Try with this query as well `NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE TODOLIST_03 SET DELETEROW =1 WHERE TASK=\"%@\"",cellText1];`

Comment: Ok I got it. Actually it was a mistake in other code.Anyway thanks for your response.. :) - @Hemang

Answer (score 0):

try following :

```
const char *sqlQuery="UPDATE TODOLIST_03 SET DELETEROW ='1' WHERE TASK= ?";

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlQuery,-1, &queryStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{   
    sqlite3_bind_text(queryStatement, 1, [cellText UTF8String], -1, NULL);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What path did you put database file at? It can not be wrote if you put the database file at the path same as project, you should put it in the sandbox for example `NSHomeDocument` where it is writeable, and you can modify code like this to track the error:

```
NSError *err;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(TODOLIST_03_DB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, &err) == SQLITE_OK)
{   
    if(err)
    {
        // NSLog error or what.
    }
}
```